# send notification to all devices using FCM

Tags: javascript, java, android, firebase, retrofit

I Using firebase realtime database to store tokens, and I can send notification to one device which I specify it
but when I read all tokens in List of string and try to send notification to all the tokens by send the list of string it just send to one device the first
any one have idea to make

**API**

```
public interface API {
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("send")
Call<ResponseBody> sendNotification(
        @Field("token") List <String> tokens,
        @Field("title") String title,
        @Field("body") String body
);
```

**Activity**

```
 binding.btnSend.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    User_Model userModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(User_Model.class);
                    tokens.add(userModel.getToken());
                    // send notification to admin
                    API api = retrofit.create(API.class);
                    Call <ResponseBody> call = api.sendNotification(tokens,binding.etNotificationTitle.getText().toString(),binding.etNotificationBody.getText().toString());
                    call.enqueue(new Callback <ResponseBody>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call <ResponseBody> call, Response <ResponseBody> response) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call <ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(AddNotificationActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    });
```

**NotificationHelper**

```
public class NotificationHelper {

public static void displayNotification(Context context,String title, String body){
    String id = "my_channel_id_01";
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Cart_Fragment.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("cartId",2);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            0,notificationIntent,0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,id)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.img_logo)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{100,1000,200,340})
            .setAutoCancel(false);
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.img_logo,"تاكيد الطلب",pendingIntent);
    builder.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat= NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    managerCompat.notify(1,builder.build());
}
}
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage message) {
    super.onMessageReceived(message);

    if (message.getNotification() != null){
        String title = message.getNotification().getTitle();
        String body = message.getNotification().getBody();

        NotificationHelper.displayNotification(getApplicationContext(),title,body);
    }
}
}
```

**index.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var {google} = require('googleapis');
var MESSAGING_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging";
var SCOPES = [MESSAGING_SCOPE];

var express = require('express');
var app = express(); 

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var router = express.Router(); 

var request = require('request');


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

router.post('/send', function(req, res){

getAccessToken().then(function(access_token){

    var title = req.body.title; 
    var body = req.body.body; 
    var token = req.body.token; 

    request.post({
        headers:{
            Authorization: 'Bearer '+access_token
        }, 
        url: "my url", 
        body: JSON.stringify(
            {
                "message":{
                    "token" : token,
                    "notification" : {
                        "body" : body,
                        "title" : title,
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }, function(error, response, body){
        res.end(body);
        console.log(body);
    });
});
});

app.use('/api', router);


function getAccessToken(){
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var key = require("./service-account.json");
    var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
        key.client_email,
        null,
        key.private_key,
        SCOPES,
        null
    );
    jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens){
        if(err){
            reject(err);
            return; 
        }
        resolve(tokens.access_token);
    });
});
}

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Please show the Java implementation

Comment: I edited the question now you can see it